# leecode hot 100, 347 Top K Frequent Elements

Tags: python, sorting

my submission is https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/submissions/912663494/

```
class Solution(object):
    def topKFrequent(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        '''counting keywords and their frequencies into a dict'''
        record = {}
        for num in nums:
            if num not in record:
                record[num] = 1
            else:
                record[num] += 1

        '''sort the dict according to the frequencies with reverse order'''
        topk = list(dict(sorted(record.items(), key=lambda items: items[1], reverse=True)))[:k]

        return topk


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sol = Solution()
    nums = [4,1,-1,2,-1,2,3]
    output = sol.topKFrequent(nums=nums, k=2)
```

this is what I got when running the code above in pycharm,
[image]

however, when I submit my answer on leecode, it is judged as a wrong answer, as below:
[image]

Could someone please tell where the problem is?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: the code you posted and the link to leetcode you provided doesn't print anything. You just save the result into output but you never print output.

Comment: What version of Python does Leetcode use? Your code relies on the assumption that when you do `list(d)` on a dictionary `d`, the items will be output in the same order they were inserted to the dictionary. But that is not guaranteed in Python versions before 3.7. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/765091

Comment: You could remove the need for that assumption by just doing `topk = sorted(record.items() ... ` without the conversion to a dict then back to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the template code you have used from LeetCode, it looks like you selected "Python" and not "Python 3". The first will run your code on Python 2.7

If you submit your code using the "Python 3" engine, your code will work.

A comment in your code says *"sort the dict"*, and then the code creates a sorted list of key/value pairs which it feeds into a new dict.

However, before Python 3.7, dicts did not maintain (insertion) order, and so on those versions the effect of calling `sorted` is lost again.

When selecting "Python 3", LeetCode will run your code with a recent version of Python, which at the time of writing is 3.10. Check the version that LeetCode uses on [support.leetcode.com](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-).